# Resolution problems with MSI R5770 Hawk through DisplayPort

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, displayport, amd-graphics-card

I just picked up a MSI R5770 Hawk card from the parts picking megathread. I run dual 2560x1600 monitors (LG W3000H, for what it's worth) but for some reason I can only get the native resolution for the monitors through the DVI interface. My previous card was a Sapphire card from about two years ago with dual DVI interfaces on the card, which worked without problems.

However, when using the DisplayPort interface with the dongle included in the package and an appropriate DVI-D Dual Link cable, windows and catalyst both detect the monitor's max resolution at 1280x800. The monitor is, however, being detected as an LG W3000H, if that matters.

I've downloaded updated drivers, and that doesn't seem to fix the problem. Any idea what, if anything, I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that displays of only up to 1920x1200 are capable through a passive DisplayPort to DVI-D Dual Link adapter. Instead, only with an expensive powered adapter is resolution of 2560x1600 possible.

As well, in my research it seems that HDMI to DVI-D Dual Link conversion also kills 2560x1600 as well. HDMI 1.3 is capable of that resolution, as is DVI-D Dual Link, however when converting from one to the other such resolution is impossible.

So basically, I'm up the creek without a paddle unless I want to drop a bunch of money for a powered adapter. Practically speaking I'd be better off RMAing the card for one with 2x DVI interfaces.